# Problem positioning these blocks in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this->[image: ideal layout]

(Black box is a signup/login section, blue is a nav bar, red is a header area with some

## text

content) I am trying to get to that outcome with this css:

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:regular,bold&subset=latin);

html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#fff;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', arial, serif;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 14px;
}
a {
  color: #2e4987;
  text-decoration: none;
}
img {
  border: 0;
  width: 250 px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}



#nwtBox {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 800px;
}
#nwtBox h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nwtBox h1 span {
  float: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#nwtBox h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  color: #333;
}
#nwtBox h3 {
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}
#nwtBox h3 img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}



#nwtBox #header {
  width: 960px;
  background-color:#fff;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  border-width:thin;
  border-color: red;
}

#nwtBox #header h1 {

  text-align: center;
}

#nwtBox #navigation {

  width: 960px;
  background-color:#fff;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  border-width:thin;
  border-color:blue;
}
#nwtBox #navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#nwtBox #navigation ul li {

  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#nwtBox #navigation ul li a {
  color: #a8a8a8;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nwtBox #navigation ul li a:hover {
  color: #2e4987;
}
#nwtBox #navigation .main-nav {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}


#nwtBox #navigation {
  float: left;
  padding: 35px 0 0 0;
}
#nwtBox #navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#nwtBox #navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#nwtBox #navigation ul li a {
  color: #a8a8a8;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nwtBox #navigation ul li a:hover {
  color: #2e4987;
}
#nwtBox #navigation .main-nav {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}



#nwtBox #signupLogin {

  float:right;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: none;
  padding: 32px 0 0 0;
  text-align: right;
  color: #999999;
  border: solid;
  border-width:thin;
  border-color:red;
}
```

and this HTML

```
<body>
<div id ="nwtBox">


   <div id ="signupLogin">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href =''> Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href =''> Log In</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  <div id = "navigation">
           <ul class="main-nav"> 
            <li class="main-nav-selected"> 
              <a href="index.php">HOME</a> 
            </li> 

             <li>              
              <a href="stuff.php">STUFF</a> 
            </li> 
            <li> 
              <a href='stuff.php'>STUFF</a> 
            </li> 
          </ul>
  </div>
 <div id ="header">
   <h1> TEXT</h1>
 </div>

  </body>
```

instead of the desired outcome, I get:
[image: bad layout]

what's wrong?

Comment: FYI, you never closed the `nwtbox` div.

Comment: You also used overflow:none, which is not a valid property. I presume you want `overflow:hidden` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear:both` to your navigation block

```
#nwtBox #navigation {
  float: left;
  padding: 35px 0 0 0;
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Floats will not interfere with relatively placed elements; content will just flow around the float. As you have both the navigation and the login box as floats, they're not affecting the positioning of the content div. If you want to leave things simple, you can simply give the content div a top margin equal to `loginHeight + loginTopMargin + navHeight + navTopMargin` and you'll be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#nwtBox #navigation {
  clear: both;
  //remove float: left;
  padding: 35px 0 0 0;
}
```

If you want to keep `float: left` in #navigation, you can add a div with style `clear: both` into HTML code.

```
<div id="signupLogin>
...
</div>

<div style="clear: both"></div>

<div id="navigation">
...
```